# Microsoft Fabric WebAPI communication

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric

A question perhaps silly, but I'm not sure where to start digging.

I have an app based on Microsoft Fabric SDK, there two stateless WebAPI services and one ASP.NET Core for Web UI  - just front end. Apparently, UI calls WebAPI's for it needs.

However sometimes one of stateless WebAPI need to communicate with another stateless WebAPI service without UI liaising. Should it make a call over http (what would be an address then), is there simpler way? Is my architecture crap?

Thanks

Comment: Not posting this as an answer because this may equally suck, or be over complicated. Public APIs are exposed via a gateway (e.g. sf reverse proxy), these are WebAPI services which have http endpoints. These in turn call internal only services. Effectively they are a proxy to the internal service and can manage their own, for example, AuthZ before calling internal service. That way any WebAPI service which needs to perform actions from other services can do so relatively easily. So basically I have Public Gateway -> WebAPI service -> Calls internal IService(s).

Comment: Thanks @Mardoxx your solution makes sense, I thought about this too, but considered it as overcomplicated. I guess in my particular case I might re-design architecture in a way that WebAPIs don't need each other and everything goes through client.

Comment: I wouldn't call @Mardoxx's solution overcomplicated, it is fairly standard architecture imo.